# PrimeFaces dataTable multiple update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to update two form components via ajax without success.
Here's the code (inside a first p:dataTable):

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
        listener="#{gestionCierres.selectionPeriodo}" 
        update=":cierreTemplateForm:tablaZonaEmpresarial :cierreTemplateForm:labelInfoPeriodo :cierreTemplateForm:tablaZonaInfo" />
```

The method selectionPeriodo in Controller is related with the updating of the second dataTabla (tablaZonaEmpresarial). The element tablaZonaInfo (third p:dataTable) is not being updated. I even tried to add a specific updating method for the dataTable tablaZonaInfo in the Controller method selectionPeriodo.

Please, can anybody see the solution?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The above referenced code:<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{gestionCierres.selectionPeriodo}" update=":cierreTemplateForm:tablaZonaEmpresarial :cierreTemplateForm:labelInfoPeriodo :cierreTemplateForm:tablaZonaInfo" />

Comment: Have you pressed F12 in your browser and watch the network traffic on that Ajax Update.  See if "tableZoneInfo" is in the Ajax response.  I have a feeling the XHTML is being updated its just the data in the table is not being updated so it looks like nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In update section you need to refer to an identifier and you need remoteCommand composant

```
<h:form id="form">
     <p:remoteCommand name="onRowSelected" update="id"/>

        <p:dataTable id="id"> 
        <p:ajax event="yourEvent" listener="#{function}" oncomplete="onRowSelected()"/>
          ...
        </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```